# SwiftUI Form Label above Text field Section Spacing

Tags: swift, forms, swiftui, spacing, sections

I am attempting to create a form in SwiftUI that has the Label above the text input field all the time.

A good example is looking at a contact on an iPhone 12. There are two standalone inputs (among others). Mobile and Notes respectively.

They look and space just how I would like mine.

No matter how I change the following code I always have a large space at the top and the fields themselves have huge spaces in between the Sections.

```
Form {

    Section() {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Field1")
            TextField("...", text: $Field1)
        }
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 0, bottom: 10, trailing: 0))
    }
  
    Section() {
            
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Field2")
            TextField("...", text: $Field2)
        }
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 0, bottom: 10, trailing: 0))
        
    }
}
```

If the Form tag here is the issue is it better to remove it and do it all manually. Apple do seem to want you to use the Form tag for cross compatibility. In my case its for iPads and iPhones.

Comment: Form is an as is View if you don’t like how it looks you have to make one yourself.

Comment: "Form is an as is View" ??

Comment: Take it or leave it as is. It is a preset look.

Comment: Your answer makes no sense. Are you trying to say that there is no way to control the spacing of Sections in the Form tag?

Comment: Yes… it is a specific look that Apple provides,

Comment: Ok. How would I create the same look outside of the Form tag (with the right spacing).

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form

Comment: VStacks, HStacks, padding, system colors, heading fonts. It is up to you.

Comment: There is nothing in Apples documentation that shows you how to do this. They want you to use the Form tag. Even though ironically their own software doesn't appear to.

Comment: No the link is just a description of what Form is. You have to create your own. If you need a SwiftUI crash course to know the basics Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)

Comment: @LanaNorth Can I ask bit which specifically in Contacts, so I can get an idea? I screenshot may help. Is it when viewing a contact's details, when editing, or where?

Comment: @LanaNorth Ah, I think I understand what part you mean now - it looks custom. I don't think that's a real `List` (probably made in UIKit, so `UITableView`). It looks like the equivalent of a `ScrollView`, with the correct background color and all custom views. Compare it to the settings app for example - the insets are completely different, and so is the spacing between sections. I think the contacts app is just all custom here, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Just open contacts and click on one of the contacts. You will see a placeholder for a picture at the top, underneath their name, underneath that the buttons message / call/ etc then underneath that the fields I describe.

Comment: To be honest I'm struggling to do it with a custom layout. It's like there is no way to create a 'margin' (from a css point of view).

Comment: Margin is similar to padding

Comment: Are you opposed to putting the field name into the header? It is not exactly like the Contacts example, but Apple changed the `Form` paradigm with `SwiftUI`. Also, as a matter of terminology, `Form()` is a view, not a tag in SwiftUI. A `.tag()` is an entirely different thing altogether, and you will cause confusion using it wrong around here.

Comment: @Yrb I realise it myself now but Form() being a view as you say makes a lot more sense to it now. I'm about to post my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My second answer to my own question. This is what I came up with.

I decided to go down the route of a separate label above a text input control using the header as the label. This does have a different look.

This is simply because the original look I was after didn't have the best UI experience.

It is possible to add extra code but it starts to get far to over complicated.

```
Form {
                    
    Section(header: Text("Field1")  // Label
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        // The padding top is larger on the first control to make it stand out more from the navigation bar title.
                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 30, leading: 5, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))) {
        TextField("Required", text: $Field1)
    }
    .textCase(nil) // I dont want the label to be all uppercase.
    
    Section(header: Text("Field2")  // Label
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 5, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))) {
        TextField("Required", text: $Field1)
    }
    .textCase(nil)
    
    Section {
        NavigationLink(destination: SomeView()) {
            Text("Next")
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
        }
    }

}
.navigationBarTitle("Main Title")
```

Answer (score 3):

As I said in my comments, you could also put your field title in as the `Section` header. Also, this is your UI, make it how you want. My only comment about it was to think of the usability when designing it. Your answer gives what looks to be a large target for the user, but in reality is only half that size. I am not saying it is wrong for your app, only that you should consider it.

```
    Form {
        
        Section(header: Text("Field1") ) {
            TextField("Required", text: $Field1)
                // With padding that is equivalent to your padding.
                .padding(.vertical, 10)
            // .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 0, bottom: 10, trailing: 0))
        }
        
        Section(header: Text("Field2") ) {
            TextField("Optional", text: $Field2)
            // Without padding...
        }
        
        Section(header: Text("Field3") ) {
            TextField("Optional", text: $Field2)
                // With padding that is determined by the system.
                .padding(.vertical)
        }
    }
```

Obviously, this gives you a different look. As you will notice, I gave you three different `.padding()` looks. One is yours, instead using `.vertical` (sets `.top` and `.bottom` to be the same) with the same constant. The next is no padding around the field. The last in allowing the system to choose your padding.

Comment: Although this doesn't create the look I want I did something similar in the end as making the whole control detect the touch is far too complicated  and I agree its not the best user experience. I'm going to edit my original answer

Comment: On another small note I found that this method didn't need the VStack.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. Without the second view, the VStack does nothing. I will edit my answer. I was more focused on the section header.

Comment: On reflection I actually prefer this look now to my original. Makes it clearer where to click as well.

Answer (score 0):

My first answer to my own question. This is what I came up with (but decided not to use).

It's pretty much what I wanted in the look.

It seems that Apple really do want to force you to do it "their way".

It is difficult to alter the Form *view* format without everything you try having some unrequired knock on effect.

I agree with some of the comments that this does look correct but it doesn't have the best UI experience.

```
Form {
            
   Section() {

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Field1")
                .font(.headline)
            TextField("Required", text: $Field1)
        }
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 0, bottom: 10, trailing: 0))

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Field2")
                .font(.headline)
            TextField("Optional", text: $Field2)
        }
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 0, bottom: 10, trailing: 0))

    }
    
    Section {
        NavigationLink(destination: SomeView()) {
            Text("Next")
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
        }
    }

}
.navigationBarTitle("Main Title")
```

Comment: You may want to add some detail about the changes you made. Answers are for posterity, so that someone else can follow along and understand the what and why. Essentially, instead of separate sections, you just grouped them into the same section. Also, from a usability standpoint, the user has to tap on the `TextField()`, not just the `VStack()` to actually be able to enter data. This may be close to how you wanted to look, but may be less than desirable for the user. YMMV.

Comment: @Yrb It would be great to see your answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).